# How can I highlight correct answers green in PHP quiz?

Tags: php

I made a quiz using PHP arrays. It's nice because you don't have to edit HTML files all the time. You can just update your array and have a new quiz ready quickly. After a big struggle, I finally found a way to count points, it's almost done. I just want to highlight correct answers green and wrong answers red. And after submitting the form all questions and options should be printed but only correct should be green and wrong should be red. I am almost there, just don't know how to target elements of the array well. Could you help me? Please have a look.
This is the array of questions:

```html
<html>
<body>
<?php 

$Questions = array(
    1 => array(
        'Question' => 'What is 2+2:',
        'Answers' => array(
            'A' => '4',
            'B' => '5',
            'C' => 'Nothing'
        ),
        'CorrectAnswer' => 'A'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'Question' => 'Where is Paris?',
        'Answers' => array(
            'A' => 'Somewhere',
            'B' => 'in Rome',
            'C' => 'in France'
        ),
        'CorrectAnswer' => 'C'
    ),
     3 => array(
        'Question' => 'What is water?',
        'Answers' => array(
            'A' => 'hydrogen and nitrogen',
            'B' => 'hydrogen and oxygen',
            'C' => 'hydrocarbon and iron'
        ),
        'CorrectAnswer' => 'B'
    )
        
);  
?>

    <form action="quiz from array.php" method="post" name="quizz" id="quiz">

    <ol>
    <?php foreach ($Questions as $QuestionNo => $Value){ ?>

    <li>
        <h4><?php echo $Value['Question']; ?></h4>            <!--Write each question-->
        <?php 
            foreach ($Value['Answers'] as $Letter => $Answer){ 
            $Label = 'question-'.$QuestionNo.'-answers-'.$Letter; /*Give label to each letter 'question-1-answers'*/
        ?>
        <div>
        <!--create radio buttons for each letter with the same name as question number-->
            <input type="radio" name="answers[<?php echo $QuestionNo; ?>]" id="<?php echo $Label; ?>" value="<?php echo $Letter; ?>" />
            <label for="<?php echo $Label; ?>"><!--<?php echo $Letter; ?>)--> <?php echo $Answer; ?> </label>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </li>

    <?php } ?>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz" />
    </form>

<?php

$correctanswers = array();

foreach ($Questions as $answers) {
    $correctanswers[] = $answers['CorrectAnswer'];
}
/*
foreach ($correctanswers as $Value) {
    echo $Value; 
}
*/

  if (isset($_POST['answers'])){
        $Answers = $_POST['answers']; 
        foreach ($Answers as $Key => $Value){
//echo $Key . $Value . '<br>'; 
        }
  }
  
   if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
  $points = 0; 
for($i=0; $i < count($correctanswers); $i++) {
    if ($Answers[$i+1] == $correctanswers[$i]) 
        $points++;
    }
    echo "You scored " . $points . "/3"; ?>
    <h3>Your answers</h3>
     <ol>
     <?php
        foreach ($Questions as $QuestionNo => $Value){ ?>
    <li>
        <h4><?php   
        echo $Value['Question']; ?></h4>
        <?php 
            foreach ($Value['Answers'] as $Letter => $Answer){ 
            
            if ($Letter == $answers['CorrectAnswer']) {
        ?>
        </li>
        <div>
            <?php echo "<span style='color: green';>" . $Letter . "</span>";
            }
else {
    echo $Letter;
}   
            ?>
            <?php echo $Answer; ?> 
        </div>
            <?php } ?>
    </li>
 
   <?php } } ?>
    </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unrelated: `<div>` is not allowed inside `<ol>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is error in your condition from my view point.
you have to simply match the POST Answer with correct answer as follows:

```
    <html>
<body>
    <?php 

    $Questions = array(
        1 => array(
            'Question' => 'What is 2+2:',
            'Answers' => array(
                'A' => '4',
                'B' => '5',
                'C' => 'Nothing'
            ),
            'CorrectAnswer' => 'A'
        ),
        2 => array(
            'Question' => 'Where is Paris?',
            'Answers' => array(
                'A' => 'Somewhere',
                'B' => 'in Rome',
                'C' => 'in France'
            ),
            'CorrectAnswer' => 'C'
        ),
         3 => array(
            'Question' => 'What is water?',
            'Answers' => array(
                'A' => 'hydrogen and nitrogen',
                'B' => 'hydrogen and oxygen',
                'C' => 'hydrocarbon and iron'
            ),
            'CorrectAnswer' => 'B'
        )
            
    );  
    ?>

    <form action="#" method="post" name="quizz" id="quiz">

    <ol>
    <?php foreach ($Questions as $QuestionNo => $Value){ ?>

    <li>
        <h4><?php echo $Value['Question']; ?></h4>            <!--Write each question-->
        <?php 
            foreach ($Value['Answers'] as $Letter => $Answer){ 
            $Label = 'question-'.$QuestionNo.'-answers-'.$Letter; /*Give label to each letter 'question-1-answers'*/
        ?>
        <div>
        <!--create radio buttons for each letter with the same name as question number-->
            <input type="radio" name="answers[<?php echo $QuestionNo; ?>]" id="<?php echo $Label; ?>" value="<?php echo $Letter; ?>" />
            <label for="<?php echo $Label; ?>"><!--<?php echo $Letter; ?>)--> <?php echo $Answer; ?> </label>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </li>

    <?php } ?>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz" />
    </form>

    <?php

    $correctanswers = array();

    foreach ($Questions as $answers) {
        $correctanswers[] = $answers['CorrectAnswer'];
    }

      if (isset($_POST['answers'])){
            $Answers = $_POST['answers']; 
            foreach ($Answers as $Key => $Value){
                //echo $Key . $Value . '<br>'; 
            }
      }
      
       if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
      $points = 0; 
    for($i=0; $i < count($correctanswers); $i++) {
        if ($Answers[$i+1] == $correctanswers[$i]) 
            $points++;
        }
        echo "You scored " . $points . "/3"; ?>
        <h3>Your answers</h3>
         <ol>
         <?php
            foreach ($Questions as $QuestionNo => $Value){ ?>
        <li>
            <h4><?php   
            echo $Value['Question']; ?></h4>
         </li>
            <?php   
                foreach ($Value['Answers'] as $Letter => $Answer){
                ?>
                <div>
                <?php
                if ($Letter == $Value['CorrectAnswer']) {
                    if($Answers[$QuestionNo] == $Value['CorrectAnswer']){
                        echo "<span style='color: green';>" . $Letter.' '.$Answer . "</span>";
                    }else{
                        echo "<span style='color: red';>" . $Letter.' '.$Answer . "</span>";
                    }
            ?>
           
                <?php 
                }
                else {
                    echo $Letter.' '.$Answer;
                }   
                ?>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
        </li>
     
       <?php } } ?>
        </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any ideas how to keep 2 highlighted answers? red and green together in case of the wrong answer green would show what was correct, red what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer myself. Thank you for all your help @Rani, I wouldn't figure it out without your prompts. So what I noticed we need additional logical conditioning, it worked when I added "AND" to the syntax. Highliting answers green also doesn't require additional nesting because correct answers don't have to be post.

```html
   
                <?php
                if ($Letter == $Value['CorrectAnswer']) {
                  echo "<b><span style='color: green'; font-weight: 900;>" . $Letter.' '.$Answer . "</span></b>";
                   }    
                                
                if ($Letter != $Value['CorrectAnswer'] AND $Letter == $Answers[$QuestionNo]) {
                            echo "<b><span style='color: red'; font-weight: 900;>" . $Letter.' '.$Answer . "</span></b>";
                    }
                                  
                      if ($Letter != $Value['CorrectAnswer'] AND $Letter != $Answers[$QuestionNo]) {
                 echo $Letter.' '.$Answer;
               } 
                }
                ?>
```